# When the page loads the following error appears "object reference not set to an instance"

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

when page load then shows error

> Object reference not set to an instance

What's wrong with the code?

HTML:

```
   <div class="col">
     <label for="lblPartyName">Image File</label>
         <div class="col-4">
           <img src="@Url.Content(Model.imagePath)" style="margin:10px; border:solid 1px" height="20" width="20" id="ImagePreview" />
           <input type="file" name="imageFile" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" onchange="ShowImagePreview(this,document.getElementById('ImagePreview'))" />

         </div>
     </div>
```

jQuery/javascript

```
<script>

    function ShowImagePreview(ImageUploder, previewImage)
    {
        if (ImageUploder.files && ImageUploder.files[0])
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $(previewImage).attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(ImageUploder.files[0]);
        }
    }


</script>
```

Model

```
[NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase imageFile { get;set; }
    public string imagePath {get;set;}
    public Quotation()
    {
        imagePath = "~/AppFiles/Images/Default.png";
    }
```

Comment: you need to find the line the error is occuring on - do you have the full error message call stack?

Comment: at first imagePath will be empty so `Url.content` trying to get the content from the empty path.

Comment: this line show error :  <img src="@Url.Content(Model.imagePath)" style="margin:10px; border:solid 1px" height="20" width="20" id="ImagePreview" />

Comment: what should i do How to correcr this. kindly hint please.

Comment: Sounds like the `imagePath` property is already assigned, but you're not returning the viewmodel by `return View(viewmodel)`, hence `Model` has null value and NRE thrown when `Model.imagePath` is used.

Comment: but I am giving a default image in the model. you can see I have created a constructor Quotation and give a default path of the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)